# DataWeave 2.0 If else condition

Tags: dataweave

Am fairly new to Dataweave, trying to achieve simple if else condition based on below

```
if (vars.country == "USA")
  { currency: "USD" }
else { currency: "EUR" }
```

This works fine. However, when I am trying with other json variables as below, it fails

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json encoding="UTF-8"
---
Name: "ABC",
if (vars.country == "USA")
  { currency: "USD" }
else { currency: "EUR" }
```

Answer (score 9):

A few ways to get it done:

Using a similar expression to what you have, you must enclose objects in `{}` when having more than one field in them

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json encoding="UTF-8"
---
{
  Name: "ABC",
  (if (vars.country == "USA")
     currency: "USD" 
   else  
     currency: "EUR")
}
```

Using the `++` function, to concatenate objects, [heres the documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-core-functions-plusplus#plusplus3)

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json encoding="UTF-8"
---
{Name: "ABC"} ++ (
    if (vars.country == "USA")
        {currency: "USD"}
    else
        {currency: "EUR"}
)
```

Finally, using the [conditional elements](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-types#conditional_elements_object) feature

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json encoding="UTF-8"
---
{
    Name: "ABC",
    (currency: "USD") if (vars.country == "USA"),
    (currency: "EUR") if not (vars.country == "USA")
}
```

Pick the one you like.

Answer (score 4):

You need to surround the condition in parenthesis like this

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json encoding="UTF-8"
var country = "UK"
---
{
    Name: "ABC",
    (if (country == "USA") currency: "USD" else currency: "EUR")
}
```

Output

```
{
  "Name": "ABC",
  "currency": "EUR"
}
```